# nary-, min-, max expression, superclass

Tags: python, function, class, expression, self

The task is to introduce three classes:
`NaryExpression, MinExpression, and MaxExpression`
to complete the UML diagram.
These three classes should support the four methods
`__init__(), __str__(), eval(), and occuring_numbers()` .
`MinExpression.eval() and MaxExpression.eval()` should return the
min and max of all the operands, respectively.

```
class NaryExpression(Expression):

    def __init__(self, *operands):
        self.operands = operands

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return super().__str__()

    def eval(self):
        return super().eval()

    def occuring_numbers():
        xoxo = []


class MaxExpression(NaryExpression):
    def __init__(self, *operands):
        super().__init__(*operands)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return super().__str__()

    def eval(self):
        return super().eval()

    def occuring_numbers():
        MaxExpression.eval()


class MinExpression(NaryExpression):
    def __init__(self, *operands):
        super().__init__(*operands)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return super().__str__()

    def eval(self):
        return super().eval()

    def occuring_numbers():
        MinExpression.eval()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    One = Constant(1)
    Two = Constant(2)
    Three = Constant(3)
    OneThousand = Constant(1000)
    Pi = Constant(round(math.pi, 2))


expr_min = MinExpression(expr1, expr2, expr3)
    expr_max = MaxExpression(expr1, expr2, expr3)

    for expr in [expr1, expr2, expr3, expr_min, expr_max]:
        print(f"{expr} = {expr.eval()}, with numbers {expr.collect_numbers()}")
        print()
```

The coding that is underneath each of the classes I wrote myself, but i don't know how to move forward. I don't know much about classes and can't figure out how im suposed to get the outcome im supposed to get:

```
min(((3) * (3)) * (3.14), (1000) / (3), (1000) - (2)) = 28.26,
with numbers {2, 3.14, 3, 1000}
max(((3) * (3)) * (3.14), (1000) / (3), (1000) - (2)) = 998,
with numbers {2, 3.14, 3, 1000}
```

(I have a lot more coding the I can post if this isn't enough to make it make sense).